# Rake task that purge just a single table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Rake command that i can run that would just delete all the fields of a table instead of dropping the whole database and recreating it. I have a table that grows large very quick, most of the data in it does not need to persist more that a week.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of asking us how to write what you need, you should try, and when it doesn't work, you ask a specific question about the problem. If you don't know how to do it, you are supposed to research solutions, and if nothing is found show us where you've searched and explain why those didn't answer your problem. As is it looks like you want us to write it for you which is off-topic. Read "[ask]", then please edit your question and show us your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try truncating the table:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")
```

From [MySQL's docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html):

> Logically, TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to a DELETE statement that
>   deletes all rows, or a sequence of DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE
>   statements.

Which seems like what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove old records from the table, without deleting current data, you need to be careful not to issue SQL statements that could lock up a large % of the records in your table. (It sounds like this table is written to frequently, so locking it for a long time is not acceptable.)

At least with mysql+innodb, you can easily end up locking more rows than just the ones you actually delete. See http://mitchdickinson.com/mysql-innodb-row-locking-in-delete/ for more info on that.

Here's a process that should keep the table fairly available, and let you remove old rows:

1. Select just the ids of a set of records which you want to remove, based on their `created_at` times.
2. Issue a `DELETE` for those records.
3. Repeat this process as long as the `SELECT` returns records.

This gives you an idea of the process...

```
max_age = 7.days.ago
batch_size = 1000
loop do
  ids = Model.select(:id).
    where('created_at < ?', max_age).
    limit(batch_size).
    map(&:id)
  Model.where(id: ids).delete_all
  break if ids.size < batch_size
end
```

Since the `SELECT` and the `DELETE` are separate statements, you won't lock any records which aren't actually being removed. The overall time taken for this process will definitely be longer than a simple `TRUNCATE TABLE`, but the benefit is you'll be able to keep recent records. `TRUNCATE` will remove everything.